# Как забрать данные из input и добавить их в разметку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Бодрого вечера, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие использовать методы, чтобы по клику на плюсик или на <kbd>Enter</kbd> забирать значение из `<input>` и добавлять его, например, в `<span>` ниже.
Накидал [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/antonessential/gz2946q8/1/), чтобы было понятнее.

```
// module__account-note

(function() {

var add = $('.jsPlus'),
    input = $('.jsInput');

    add.click(function(){

    });

})();
```

Comment: Получить значение поля ввода можно с помощью метода [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), а добавить в спан с помощью метода [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полный функциональный пример и никакого jQuery (найс верстка кстати):

```js
var addNote = document.querySelector(".module__account-note__str-3");

var input = document.querySelector(".jsInput");

var noteContainer = document.querySelector(".module__account-note__container");

function addTextNoteFromInput() {
  var value = input.value;
  if (value.trim().length < 1) {
    alert("Длина заметки слишком короткая");
  } else {
    var child = document.createElement("span");
    child.setAttribute("class", "module__account-note__str-4");
    child.innerText = value;
    noteContainer.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    noteContainer.appendChild(child);
  }
}

function pressEnter(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    addTextNoteFromInput();
  }
}

addNote.addEventListener("click", addTextNoteFromInput, false);

window.addEventListener("keydown", pressEnter, false);
```

```css
input[type='text'],
textarea,
select {
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: 'helveticaneuecyr-roman-webfont';
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
  -moz-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
  -ms-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
  -o-transition: ease-in-out .2s;
  transition: ease-in-out .2s;
  color: #242424;
  border: none;
  border: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: transparent;
}

.module__account-note {
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 40px 38px;
  background: #2c2c2c;
}

.jsPlus {
  color: white;
}

.module__account-note__str {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffc215;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
}

.module__account-note__row {
  padding: 18px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
}

.module__account-note__str-3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.module__account-note__str-2 {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #797979;
  border: none;
}

.module__account-note__str-4 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="module__account-side__bottom">
  <div class="module__account-note">
    <span class="module__account-note__str">БЛОКНОТ</span>
    <div class="module__account-note__row row between">
      <input class="jsInput module__account-note__str-2" type="text" placeholder="Оставить заметку" />
      <span class="module__account-note__str-3 jsPlus">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="module__account-note__container">
      <span class="module__account-note__str-4">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба"</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Все очень просто.

```
    $('#plus').on('click', function(){
    $('#p').html($('#price').val());
});
```

А вот, собственно, и демонстрация https://jsfiddle.net/h3a1d7qr/

Answer (score 0):

Используй метод [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), чтобы получить доступ к значению `<input>`, и затем просто добавь это в качестве текста в нужный тебе элемент

```
(function() {

    var add = $('.jsPlus'),
        input = $('.jsInput');

        add.click(function(){
           $('yourElement').text(input.val());
        });

})();
```